# Import Keynote Animation to iMovie

Tags: keynote, imovie, video-editing

I have a Keynote file with a lot of animations on the slides. I wish to record myself giving a presentation while playing the slides in full screen as a movie.

Is there a way to export Keynote animations to a video format so that I can combine my audio recording with these animations in iMovie?

Answer (score 1):

Found the answer:

1. Go to `Play` -> `Record Slideshow`.
2. Go to `File` -> `Export To` -> `QuickTime` -> `Slideshow Recording`.